# Avoiding using a dirty template tag - I'm sure there's a simple solution

Tags: django

I'm having a mental block, here.

I've got my project 90% working, but trying to figure out the best way to do something without using a dirty custom template tag.

I have 2 classes (in addition to the default django `User` model). `Echo`, and then `Report`. `Report` has 2 foreign keys: `User`, and `Echo`.

Basically, a user can create a report which references himself and also an echo. What I want do to is go to the home page and it'll list all the echos (say ~15), and then which ones they have reported.

e.g. if there are 15 echos, and the user has reported echos 3, 7, and 9 there will be a list of 15 echos with *unreported* next to all of them, except with 3, 7 and 9, where it'll say: *reported*.

Most of it is done. I've created a list of echos in a view using:

```
echos_list = Echo.objects.order_by('name')
```

and a list of reports for the logged-in user with:

```
user_reports = Report.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

However, in the template, I would need to do something like

```
{% if user_reports.filter(echo=echo.name).count > 0 %}Complete{% else %}Incomplete{% endif %}
```

...but of course I can't do this because you can't use filters in templates. What would you advise I do?

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, redirect
from dseapp.models import Echo,Report
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

@login_required
def dse_index(request):
    echos_list = Echo.objects.order_by('name')                  #We'll use this to create the entire list of echos
    user_reports = Report.objects.filter(user=request.user)     #We'll use this to make a list of reports for the current user
    return render_to_response('dseapp/dse.html', {'echos_list':echos_list,'user_reports':user_reports},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Echo</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    {% for echo in echos_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{echo.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="/report/{{echo.name}}">
        {% if user_reports.filter(echo=echo.name).count > 0 %}Complete{% else %}Incomplete{% endif %}
        </a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<a href="/logout/">Logout</a>
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Echo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image1_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image1_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image2_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image2_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image3_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image3_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image4_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    image4_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    hr_rest = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    hr_low = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    hr_high = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    lesion1_ffr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion1_ifr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion2_ffr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion2_ifr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion3_ffr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion3_ifr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion4_ffr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion4_ifr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion5_ffr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    lesion5_ifr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    echo = models.ForeignKey(Echo)
    answer_1 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_2 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_3 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_4 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_5 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_6 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_7 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_8 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_9 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_10 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_11 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_12 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_13 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_14 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_15 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_16 = models.IntegerField()
    answer_17 = models.IntegerField()
    ischaemic = models.BooleanField()
    confidence = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.__unicode__() + " / " + self.echo.__unicode__()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute this in the view. `echos_list` should be a list containing dictionaries with, for each `Echo`, whether it is completed or not.

```
echos_list = []
for echo in Echo.objects.order_by('name'):
    echos_list.append({
        'object': echo,
        'complete': user_reports.filter(echo=echo.name).count() > 0
    }]
```

You can then update your template to be:

```
{% for echo in echos_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{echo.object.name}}</td>
    <td><a href="/report/{{echo.object.name}}">
    {% if echo.complete %}Complete{% else %}Incomplete{% endif %}
    </a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This seems to work great, except it only seems to pass the first entry of the list: http://pastebin.com/MWr18gtc - if I then do     {{ echos_list }} in the template it only shows [{'object': <Echo: 1>, 'complete': False}] when actually there are 3 echos (so it's not just an off by 1 error!)

Comment: That's because your return statement is inside the for loop. So it return after the first iteration through the loop. You need to unindent the return statement to have all the Echo elements.